# Can you run a one-way ANOVA in R with only access to the means and not the entire data?

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to run an ANOVA test in R, but I do not have access to the entire data and only know the means of the three groups.

Here is an example of what my data looks like:

```
avg_ikdc <- c(49.3, 79.1, 82)
avg_kujala <- c(56.5, 86.5, 89.3)
avg_vas <- c(3.8, 2.5, 1.9)
f_u <- c("pre","short","mid")
combined <- data.frame(avg_ikdc, avg_kujala, avg_vas, f_u)
combined
```

Then, I am trying to run an ANOVA using the function available in R. The goal is to run 3 separate ANOVAs for the three columns based on the f_u column. First, I just tried to run an ANOVA for avg_ikdc based on f_u:

```
ikdc_aov <- anova(avg_ikdc ~ f_u, data=combined)
summary(ikdc_aov)
```

However, when I run this code, it does not return the typical output from an ANOVA in R - this is what is shows:

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
f_u          2  655.2   327.6
```

I was wondering if I am using the wrong function, or if there is some other way to compute an ANOVA with just 3 means as opposed to each data point used to determine these means. Thanks!

Comment: You only have the means and not the variances? There’s not a lot you can do there then. If you want statistical advice, ask for help at [stats.se] instead. This really isn’t a specific R programming question that’s appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: To follow up on that, there are some packages (maybe a now-archived psych-related package, I don't remember?) that will do ANOVA based on summary statistics, but as @MrFlick suggests, without knowing the within-group variance you're stuck/this will be impossible.

Comment: If you do have the within group means, variances (or standard devaitions) and sample sizes, even code that doesn't work from summary stats can be made to do so simply by simulating data that exactly reproduces those summary stats. Unless you need to do anova from summaries semi-regularly this is so simple (`scale(rnorm(n))*sd+mean` applied to each group, perhaps via `tapply` or `sapply`, or relevant tidyverse functions) as to often be faster than locating a package with a specialized function, . installing it, finding the function you need in it and learning how to use it.